# gpg decrypt php works in terminal not in shell_exec

Tags: php, gnupg, pgp

```
shell_exec("gpg --batch --passphrase LongButPlainPassword -o /var/www/html/decrypt/save/".$filename."  --decrypt /var/www/html/decrypt/save/orig/".$filename);
```

I have searched many places this works in terminal but not in shell_exec(). Am I misunderstanding how this works? The destination folder has 777 permissions.

Comment: Giving world write permissions to a directory is a very bad idea, especially when it's a subdirectory of your web server root. Think about **who** is running the command from the terminal, versus when you're doing it from PHP...

Comment: Thanks, yeah it really was a trouble shoot that didn't work out. Its not live at the moment and ill secure it when I'm done.

Comment: Did you try to get the stderr output (via 2>&1) ?